# How to add declare to existing object (typing augmentation) in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Last version of lodash now has a few new functions. For example: https://lodash.com/docs#nth.

But lodash typings are for old version and hasn't those functions.

```
import _ = require('lodash');
```

How I can add declaration of those functions to `_` object?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your typings file you can see the basic LoDashStatic interface that you can extend:

```
import old = require('lodash')

interface LodashExt extends old.LoDashStatic {
    nth(n: Array<any>, i: number) : LodashExt
    // . . .
}

var _ = <LodashExt>old

_.add(1, 2)

_.nth(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)
```

That should be enough for simple cases. You might want to put the above declarations to a module and just export your new _ value.

Comment: Now I'm doing so. But I want without new variable.