# How to augment process.env in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

`process.env` is of type `ProcessEnv` with this definition:

```
export interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

I'd like to augment this TypeScript interface so that it contains the keys specific to my app, so that the result is something like:

```
export interface ProcessEnv {
    MY_VARIABLE_1: string;
    MY_OTHER_VARIABLE: string;
    [key: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

I cannot find a way to do it, I guess it will be `declare module` or `declare namespace` somewhere but cannot find a specific way to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you need such typing ? For autocomplete or verification ? For autocomplete your example should work just fine. For verification - your extra fileds do not make `[key:string]:string` any more specific.

Comment: It's for autocompletion. (Augmentation can only add to interfaces, not remove from them, so the indexer will always be there.)

Comment: So what is your question then? How to redefine a type from third-party library ? Have you tried using `as` ? Or you want a cleaner solution ?

Comment: The question is how to write augmentation (I guess `declare namespace ...`) so that when I do `process.env.`, the IDE suggests my custom variables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398009/how-to-add-declare-to-existing-object-typing-augmentation-in-typescript

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `ProcessEnv` must be inside the `namespace NodeJS` and doesn't need to declare the `[key: string]: string | undefined;`, it inherits from the initial `ProccessEnv`.

```typescript
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface ProcessEnv {
    MY_VARIABLE_1: string;
    MY_OTHER_VARIABLE: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the `[key: string]: string | undefined` indexer? It's too permissive for me; I could still fat-finger something.

Comment: If you don't remove the default declaration (`[key: string]: string | undefined`), then it doesn't make sense to extend `process.env`. (1) Anything you add to `process.env` but don't declare will be accepted (`string: string`) and (2) anything you declare has to be `string`, or else it will clash with the `[key: string]: string | undefined` rule. Besides, even without Typescript, anything you add to `process.env` will be type `string`. Conclusion: don't worry about extending `process.env`, just make sure to document and include the variables in your code - the current type declaration is fine.

Comment: you can remove the [key:string] from the original .d.ts (not recommended, but one option). But better than that, what I do is JSDoc the real variables so that at least you can confirm you're using the right thing by hovering the mouse and seeing its description.

Comment: Just discovered you can remove the indexer by changing interface to type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `[key: string]: string | undefined` indexer from `process.env` declaration and thus restrict the use of `env` to explicitly declared names, you can declare process as variable:

```js
declare var process : {
  env: {
    NODE_ENV: string
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do I need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

without `export {}` doesn't work for me (Next 14.0.4), this is what works:

```
// environment.d.ts
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      DATABASE_URL: string;
      NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: string;
    }
  }
}

export {}; // add here
```