# How to copy additional files e.g. config/config.yaml, to .next folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, next.js

I have following folder structure for NextJS project:

_posts/
components/
hooks/
config/ <--- includes config.yaml file for server
pages/
public/
.env.local
...

`yarn build` copies all dependencies correctly except `config/` folder. It includes files that are needed to run `server`.

Is there any way to tell nextJS compiler/bundler to copy `config/` folder inside `.next` folder?

Things that I tried:

1. Updating 'build' step in package.json with `cp -rf config/ .next/ && next build` --- **does not help. `next build` cleans `.next` folder. Disabling the auto-clean isn't useful.**
2. Going through documentation of `next.config.js` to see if there is a pre-build hook that can be used. --- **there isn't any.**
3. Copying `config/` folder after `next build` --- **doesn't help as `next build` fails complaining about missing `config/config.yaml` file.**

Comment: Next.js comes with the to manage this kind of configuration through environment variables and dotenv files. I would recommend using the builtin approach rather than rolling your own solution. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: Yeah. I actually tried with that. However, when I tried to use an environment variable e.g. `process.env.POSTGRES_URL`, typescript intellisense and compilation failing stating that it can be undefined (when passed to Sequelize constructor). Forcing TS to recognize it as non-undefined by using `process.env.POSTGRES_URL!` didn't help either.

Comment: Ah that is a relatively easy problem to solve, you can do it the easy way (`(process.env as any).POSTGRES_URL`) or the "right" way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008773/how-to-augment-process-env-in-typescript

Comment: I tried the "right" way but it didn't help. I could see the intellisense in VSCode though. I will try with `((process.env as any).POSTGRES_URL)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @kyle, using `((process.env as any).POSTGRES_URL` resolved the build issue.

I had another issue to run tests using `mocha`. I ended up using `dotenv` in the tests' execution flow (to load `.env.test.local`).