# Unable to extend interface `ProcessEnv` in basic app setup

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a basic setup for Nodejs with Typescript.

I'm trying to extend the `ProcessEnv` interface to get type support for variables, but nothing is showing up.

The structure is as simple as it gets,

```
/
├── src
|   └ index.ts
├── node.augmentations.ts
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

In `node.augmentations.ts`, I have,

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    HOST: string;
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to access `process.env.HOST` in `src/index.ts`, but I neither get any errors nor do I get autosuggest support.

I've tried everything I could find online, nothing worked.

What am I missing here?

[image: typescript-node-forked-7w1k1n]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to augment process.env in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008773/how-to-augment-process-env-in-typescript)

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: It works in your sandbox... What's your tsconfig?